# eclipse axis2 web service error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am now using axis2 and using Eclipse generate a web service project. Now I am in trouble.

Java File:

```
public class WebServiceServer{

public Map<String,String> getConfigInfo(List<Map<String,Object>> objectList){
    Map<String,String> returnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        //do something
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return returnMap;
}
```

}

I am now using Eclipse Java EE 3.6 ,I like wtp plugin. Now, I use Eclipse and right click on my project then New-->Other-->Web Service.

But when I start tomcat, error has come.

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: 
The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:433)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:370)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:397)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

[ERROR] The WebServiceServer service, which is not valid, caused The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class



 Someone told me that axis2 cannot deal with the return type is List or Map?
 Any replay is welcome. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the above answer, only Axis2 Trunk version (1.7.0-SNAPSHOT) has the support for collections such as Lists, maps.

Unless you are using Axis2 trunk version (1.7.0-SNAPSHOT) you cannot use them. You have to use  Arrays with other versions of Axis2.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Answer (score 1):

> Someone told me that axis2 cannot deal with the return type is List or
>   Map?

That someone was correct.

You'll need to return arrays, or in your case, arrays of arrays.